# Can't serve static index.html with Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm new to Spring and I find it is really hard to get into it. I want to serve a static index.html but it doesn't work. [image]

I used [this](https://spring.io/blog/2013/12/19/serving-static-web-content-with-spring-boot) tutorial but can't access index.html with:
http://localhost:8080/ or 
http://localhost:8080/src/main/public/index.html

IndexHtmlController:

```
package de.phip1611.springboot_test_1;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;

@Controller
public class IndexHtmlController {}
// due to https://spring.io/blog/2013/12/19/serving-static-web-content-with-spring-boot
// this should be enough..
```

[image]

Comment: What is the value of `server.contextPath` property?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Can you try the below:

1. Move `index.html` to `src/main/resources/static` folder
2. In the application.properties file of spring boot, set `server.contextPath` to `/`. (i.e. `server.contextPath=/`)

Answer (score 0):

I have a html file in src/main/resources/static folder and added below in application.yml but it didn't work for me either. On tomcat start ,localhost:8080 shows a 404 and webpage shows whitelabel error. But for localhost:8080/hello.html I see a 200 response code when inspect but no contents of html on webpage .

```
server:
  servlet:
    context-path: /
  port: 8080
```