# No redirect to index.html for static resources inside a folder(pubilc spring boot)

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have a spring boot application with reactjs. Issue I am facing is not redirecting to root path.
I have one controller(simplest thing), it has one method mapped to root path("/").

And, I have placed index.html to all the places i.e public folder/ static folder and templates folder.

but when I am navigating to http://localhost:8080/ then it is going to error page.

link followed :- https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/react-and-spring-data-rest/

even tried:- [Can't serve static index.html with Spring Boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40008958/cant-serve-static-index-html-with-spring-boot)

I have dependency of "spring-boot-starter-web" with version 1.3.5.RELEASE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please make sure you have added **Thymeleaf** to your dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Then, you can easily return `index.html` template (placed in `resources/templates/`) from your controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/")
public String index() {
    return "index";
}
```